# How do you replace all characters except last 4 with asterisks in php

Tags: php

I have a variable called `$CARD_NUM` which can have any amount of numbers more than 4.

How can I replace all but the last 4 characters in this string with asterisks (*)?

For example if:

```
$CARD_NUM = '123456789012'
```

The resultant string should be:

```
********9012
```

Comment: Have you searched something? `str_replace()` - http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 27):

If the variable is guaranteed to be at least 4 digits long, then

```
$CARD_NUM = "123456789012";
echo str_repeat('*', strlen($CARD_NUM) - 4) . substr($CARD_NUM, -4);
```

should do it, [see it in action!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b17086acda1eddda52b81f4d9986dab219e8b62)

Finally, as DougW suggested in a comment, if the string is NOT guaranteed to be at least 4 digits, then this should do it

```
$CARD_NUM = "123456789012";
echo str_repeat('*', MAX(4, strlen($CARD_NUM)) - 4) . substr($CARD_NUM, -4);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked out perfectly fine

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helped you feel free to upvote and/or accept it!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  This is straight forward and works like a charm!

Comment: Would have added this as an answer but this question was voted closed for some dumb reason.  If your string isn't guaranteed to be at least 4 characters, here's a simple fix to work with strings of any length.  `str_repeat('*', MAX(4, strlen($CARD_NUM)) - 4) . substr($CARD_NUM, -4);`

Comment: @DougW I added your comment to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$CARD_NUM = "123456789012";
$replacement = '*';
echo preg_replace('/\d(?=\d{4})/m', $replacement, $CARD_NUM);
```

If you wanna view 2 or 3 digits only to be displayed just replace `4` in `'/\d(?=\d{4})/m'` to  whatever number of digits you want.